# Filing 1040-NR when I have been outside the US the entire year?

Tags: income-tax, state-income-tax, income-tax-refund, form-1040x

Hypothetical Scenario:

- I work as an employee (not a contractor) of a US corporation based in UT
- I am not a permanent resident of the US (i.e. no green card or US citizenship)
- I am an Indian citizen and live in India and work remotely
- I get my paycheck credited to my US bank account
- My employer deducts the federal and state taxes
- Question-1 : Can I file 1040NR if I have been outside of the US for the full year ?
  (my assumption is that it is for someone who has been in the US for less than a specified days. I am not sure if this is  valid for someone who has not been in the US at all)
- Question-2 : If answer to Question 1 is yes , approximately how much standardized return should I expect on federal tax and state tax ? Should all of it be returned since i will also claim credit for the taxes I have to pay on the same income in India

I am aware of form W8BEN which I can submit to my employer to declare that I am a non US person and have them deduct nothing from my income. I am just trying to have minimal modifications at my employers side

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can still file a 1040nr. You are a [nonresident alien](https://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-1040NR,-U.S.-Nonresident-Alien-Income-Tax-Return) and were:

> engaged in a trade or business in the United States

Normally, assuming your withholding was correct, you would get a minimal amount back. Income earned in the US is definitely [Effectively Connected Income](https://www.irs.gov/Individuals/International-Taxpayers/Effectively-Connected-Income-%28ECI%29) and is

> taxed at the graduated rates that apply to U.S. citizens and resident aliens.

However, there is a [tax treaty between US and India](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-trty/inditech.pdf), and it suggests that you would be taxed on the entirety of the income by India. This suggests to me that you would get everything that was withheld back.